# Assign Item from One List to Another by ID

Tags: c#, list

I need some help in being able to get a value from one list and assign it to another list. I have created a simplified version of what I am doing at the moment.

Given the following:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Car
    {
        public Car(string maker)
        {
            this.maker = maker;
            this.counter = 0;
        }

        public string maker { get; set; }
        public int counter { get; set; }
    }

    class CarModel
    {
        public CarModel(string maker, string model)
        {
            this.maker = maker;
            this.model = model;
        }

        public string maker { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
    }

        class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
            carList.Add(new Car("Honda"));
            carList.Add(new Car("Toyota"));
            carList.Add(new Car("Nissan"));
            carList.Add(new Car("Ford"));
            carList.Add(new Car("Dodge"));

            List<CarModel> modelList = new List<CarModel>();
            modelList.Add(new CarModel("Honda", "Accord"));
            modelList.Add(new CarModel("Honda", "Civic"));
            modelList.Add(new CarModel("Honda", "Pilot"));
            modelList.Add(new CarModel("Ford", "F150"));
            modelList.Add(new CarModel("Ford", "F250"));
            modelList.Add(new CarModel("Ford", "Edge"));
            modelList.Add(new CarModel("Ford", "Fusion"));
            modelList.Add(new CarModel("Nissan", "GT-R"));
            modelList.Add(new CarModel("Nissan", "Versa"));
            modelList.Add(new CarModel("Dodge", "Ram"));

            var grouped = modelList.GroupBy(s => s.maker, (key, values) => new { Maker = key, Count = values.Count() });

            foreach (var i in grouped)
            {
                foreach (Car car in carList)
                {
                    if (i.Maker == car.maker)
                    {
                        car.counter = i.Count;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (Car car in carList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(car.maker + " | " + car.counter.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am obtaining the Count value from the grouped variable and assigning it to the Car object via the equality in the maker field.

The ForEach loop I am using handles the assignment pretty well, but I know that when the number of items increases for each list, then the loop will take longer to execute.

The result I am getting is as below (which is what I require)

```
Honda  | 3
Toyota | 0
Nissan | 2
Ford   | 4
Dodge  | 1
```

I believe there would be a better way to do this. I looked at the Intersect method, but doing that would still require me to loop through the list to assign the values.

I have tried doing an Outer join on the list, like:

```
var combined = from a in carList
                           from b in grouped
                           .Where(bOuter => bOuter.Maker == a.maker)
                           .DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new
                           {
                               maker = a.maker,
                               count = b.Count
                           };

            foreach (var i in combined)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.maker + " - " + i.count);
            }
```

But I am getting a Null Exception error.

Appreciate any inputs / suggestions.

Comment: Toyota doesn't have a model list so use this : count = b == null ? -1 :b.Count.  Or this : count = b == null ? null :(int?)b.Count

Comment: Is the LINQ query the correct way to do this? I did made the change you suggested and it worked fine. I am just wondering if there's a better / suggested way of achieving this?

Comment: Yes.  With Linq you sometimes have to consider the null conditions.  Linq is a good method in this case.

Answer (score 0):

What you need comes from the logic. You want to set for every Car maker the number of models that are in that list. Therefore, for each car maker the counter would be equal to all cars from modelList where the maker is equal to the maker in the carList. Make sure have also "using System.Linq;" .

```
        foreach(Car carObject in carList)
        {
            carObject.counter = modelList.Where(x => x.maker == carObject.maker).ToList().Count;
        }
```